# How to fill XFA (PDF) form automatically?

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xfa

I'm looking for a free option to fill a XFA PDF form. I know that iText is an option but their commercial prices are too expensive for me, I'd prefer something fully open-source. There is PDFBox but it doesn't seem to allow for inserting data into XFA forms, or at least there's very little explaining how to.

I simply need to fill in certain fields in my form with certain data in a text file. Can you recommend or direct me to a solution? Thank you greatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XFA is an enterprise product, with enterprise pricing…

XFA consists of an XML part and a PDF part which represents kind of what is in the XML part.

You may try to fill data into the XML part, and then see whether Acrobat/Reader can render it properly. No guarantee that it works, but worth a try. If that does work, you'd have shifted the problem to something maybe a bit more managable.

Comment: Thank you Max. Appreciate the straightforward reply.